# How can I change the text color and the tint color of radiobuttons in a Alert?

Tags: java, android-studio, radio-button, android-alertdialog

Right now I have a button and when clicked it pops up with an AlertDialog with 3 radiobuttons. [image]

I want to change the text color and the tint color to match what I have on the rest of the app. Besides the call to the method this is all the code I have for the Alert:

```
public void CreateAlertDialogWithRadioButtonGroup()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings.this, R.style.myDialogTheme);

        if(sharedPreferences.getString("units", "").equals("metric"))
            chosenUnit = 0;
        else if(sharedPreferences.getString("units", "").equals("imperial"))
            chosenUnit = 1;
        else
            chosenUnit = 2;

        builder.setTitle("Select the Unit for the Temperature");

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(values, chosenUnit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
            {
                switch(item)
                {
                    case 0://Celsius
                        unitsEditor.putString("units", "metric");
                        unitsEditor.commit();
                        break;
                    case 1://Fahrenheit
                        unitsEditor.putString("units", "imperial");
                        unitsEditor.commit();
                        break;
                    case 2://Kelvin
                        unitsEditor.putString("units", "");
                        unitsEditor.commit();
                        break;
                }
                alertDialog1.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog1 = builder.create();
        alertDialog1.show();
    }
```

I have tried to change them in the style but none of it works, I can only seem to change the textcolor of the alert and not the radiobuttons. Any idea? I do not have a layout for the Alert so I can't do a findById for the radiogroup. I am doing this in Java and not Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to RadioButton XML the app:buttonTint option as follows:

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_metric"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonTint="@color/colorRed" />
```

Also, go to color.xml and add the color you want to be the RadioButton

Comment: That won't work as I'm not using a separate layout for the alert

Comment: You can change the primary and accent color in the style.xml at your myDialogTheme.